# Vuetify: v-list-item, no spacing when using v-slot:prepend

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm currently creating a side navigation with v-navigation-drawer. Most of my items use an icon, but i want to create some with custom behaviour too. Sadly the title in v-slot:title does not align with the title in the v-list-item that uses prepend-icon. How can i achieve that behaviour.

```
    <v-navigation-drawer
        location="left"
        width="250"
        permanent
    >
      <v-list>
        <v-list-item prepend-icon="mdi-account" title="Profile" to="/profile"></v-list-item>
        <v-list-item prepend-icon="mdi-email-fast" title="Feedback" to="/feedback"></v-list-item>

        <v-list-item>
          <template v-slot:prepend>
                <v-progress-circular
                    model-value="30"
                    size="25"
                    color="deep-orange-lighten-2"
                ></v-progress-circular>
          </template>

          <template v-slot:title>
                Progress
          </template>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve a problem like this, I would inspect the DOM and compare the standard prepend element vs. the v-slot prepend element. Everything is replaced when using v-slot, so the key is to figure out what HTML and/or styling is different when using vs. not using a v-slot.

### Debugging

Standard prepend element looks something like this:

```html
<div class="v-list-item__prepend">
  <i class="mdi-email-fast mdi v-icon notranslate v-theme--light v-icon--size-default" aria-hidden="true" density="default"></i>
  <div class="v-list-item__spacer"></div>
</div>
```

The prepend v-slot looks more like this:

```html
<div class="v-list-item__prepend">
  <div class="v-progress-circular v-progress-circular--visible v-theme--light text-deep-orange-lighten-2" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="30" style="width: 25px; height: 25px;">
    <svg>...</svg>
  </div>
  <div class="v-list-item__spacer"></div>
</div>
```

Adding the classes from the `<i>` element to `<v-progress-circular>` fixes the spacing issue. There are additional styles added by doing this though. By studying the CSS or just by removing classes one at a time, we can narrow it down to v-progress-circular needing just the "v-icon" class.

The actual effect of this class is that `width: 32px` gets set on the `v-list-item__spacer` div.  If you inspect the `v-list-item__spacer` in your custom v-slot, you see the width is 0 until you add the "v-icon" class. You probably don't want all the other styles that come with "v-icon" though so you can leave off the class and just apply the 32px.

To do so, add a custom class, e.g. "customPrepend" to your one v-list-item so you can come up with a selector for the necessary CSS

### Solution

```html
<v-list-item class="customPrepend">
  <template #prepend>
    <v-progress-circular
      model-value="30"
      size="25"
      color="deep-orange-lighten-2"
    ></v-progress-circular>
  </template>
  <template #title> Progress </template>
</v-list-item>
```

```css
<style scoped>
.customPrepend :deep(.v-list-item__prepend .v-list-item__spacer) {
  width: 32px;
}
</style>
```

[Vuetify Playground example](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: Such a quality answer. Just a shame people nowadays don't vote up anymore.